# using tap inplace of map and to_h in ruby

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hash

Suppose I have a function which returns a hash after mapping user's data with its id.
Something like this -

```
  def user_data(u_data)
    u_data.map { |u| [u['id'], u] }.to_h
  end
```

How can I use a tap method with this code block for the same functionality? Thanks

Comment: `tap` doesn't really make sense here. Why do you think it would? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong ...this creates an array and creates a hash. that's I wanted to use {}.tap
btw just wanted to understand how can we use .tap on fly (I am very new to ruby)

Comment: It sounds like you're unfamiliar with how `#tap` works, are you asking for an explanation? Your question doesn't really make sense. It's like asking, "how do I use a napkin to make a sandwich"? Sure, the sandwich shop gives you both when you order, but the napkin wasn't really relevant in the sandwich making.

Comment: That creates an array of key/value pairs (i.e. an array of arrays) and then uses `#to_h` to convert that to a single hash. You could also say `u_data.each_with_object({}) { |u, h| h[u['id']] = u }` to get the same result. You could say `{}.tap { |h| u_data.each { |u| h[u['id']] = u } }` but that's just going to make whoever reads the code wonder what you were trying to do and why you were using `#tap` to do it.

Comment: That's the answer @muistooshort, there are many ways to _map_ the elements from one object to another by modifying their key/values and tap is one of them.

Comment: @SebastianPalma *an* answer but it is a very odd use of `#tap` so I am reluctant to do any more than a drive-by comment.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh : `x.tap {}` just returns `x` unmodified. If someone will beat you unless he sees a `tap` in your code, and since you ask to _use a tap method with **this** code block_, you can throw in as many _taps_ as you like, for instance `(u_data.tap {}.map { |u| [u['id'], u] }.to_h).tap {'I am in a tappy mood'}`.

Comment: @user1934428 But the block is free to modify the content of `x` so you can do it with `{}.tap { |h| ... }` as noted above.

Comment: I see. And you are right: This would be a very odd usage of `tap`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use a tap method with this code block for the same functionality?

You can't. It makes no sense to use [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap) here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#tap` for this but you need to turn the problem inside out. You want a hash as the result and `x.tap { ... }` returns `x` so `x` would be the hash you want to return. So you can say `{}.tap { |h| ... }` and let the block fill in `h` with the desired format:

```
def user_data(u_data)
  {}.tap do |h|
    u_data.each do |u|
      h[u['id']] = u
    end
  end
end
```

That's pretty unpleasant and I would hope that no one would do that in real code.

You'd be better of using your current `#to_h` approach or maybe going with [`#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def user_data(u_data)
  u_data.each_with_object({}) { |u, h| h[u['id']] = u }
end
```

or, closer to your original, [`#to_h`][2] with a block:

```
def user_data(u_data)
  u_data.to_h { |u| [u['id'], u] }
end
```

Comment: Depending on the Ruby version, you can pass a block to `to_h` (`u_data.to_h { |u| [u['id'], u] }`).

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thanks for that, I must have missed change to `#to_h` or overlooked it because I habitually go to `#each_with_object` for a lot things like this.